# Transfer folder from one SFTP server to another every day

Tags: sftp

I have two different servers. I use WinSCP to transfer a folder manually:

- I connect to SFTP on SVR-01 -> Transfer folder to my local machine
- I connect to SFTP on SVR-02 -> Transfer folder from my local machine to SVR-02

**What I want?:**

I would like to do it automatically.

Example: in a command OR script, the **SVR-01** transfer folder `/opt/home/files-everyday/` to **SVR-02** `/opt/backup/`

When transfer is finished, delete `/opt/home/files-everyday/` from SVR-01.

This should be done every day.

One folder is created every day by date "20150613" in SVR-01 and this folder to be automatically transferred to the SVR-02.

Comment: You start the `sftp` command on one of the "server" systems, not on your local system. Then you can simply "push over" what you want. And if you want to be really cool, then use `rsync` over ssh instead of `sftp`. Way more elegant in the end ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) from a Windows batch file:

```
@echo off

mkdir %temp%\intermediate

winscp.com /log=c:\path\log.log /command ^
    "open sftp://user1:password1@server1.example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 87:d6...a7""" ^
    "get /opt/home/files-everyday/* %temp%\intermediate\" ^
    "open ftps://user2:password2@server2.example.com/" ^
    "put %temp%\intermediate\* /opt/backup/" ^
    "session 1" ^
    "rm /opt/home/files-everyday/*" ^
    "exit"

rmdir /q /s %temp%\intermediate
```

---

Then [use the Windows scheduler to run the script regularly (every day)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).